# Few calculus questions

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

1. $\lim \dfrac{(-1+i\sqrt{3})^{3n+1}}{8^n-1}$

I have no idea how to find limits of complex numbers.

1. $\sum \dfrac{(n!)^2}{2^{n^{2}}}x^n, x \in$ C

I have no idea how to find limits of complex numbers.

1. $\lim (\sqrt[3]{x^3+x^2+x+1}-\sqrt{x^2+x+1}*\dfrac{\ln(e^x+x)}{x})$

I tried multiplying to and bottom by $1/x$. But that yields $(1-1*1)/0$, which isn't useful. And l'Hospital's rule looks too long.

For these three, I have no idea at all...

1. $\sum ($arccot $n-\arcsin (1/n))$
2. $\sum (\cot (\dfrac{\pi n}{4n-2})-\sin \dfrac{\pi n}{2n+1})$
3. $\sum (\arccos (1-1/n) n^a), a \in $ R

Thanks! All sums and limits are to infinity. For sums, convergence/divergence is enough.

For the last three sums, WolframAlpha says that by the comparison test they converge, diverge and depending on $a$, respectively. However, I don't know what to compare them to.

Comment: Since this is homework, you should contribute with your own thoughts and attempts.

Comment: Hi. It looks like you are new here. We are generally very willing to help, but we like users to show the work that they've done towards solving the problem on their own first. If you can edit your question to show what you've done so far, and where you are stuck, then you will get a much better response.

Comment: Just a few? They look like a lot to me and you can get more people to help you if you show your work first.

Comment: Limits for $z$ going to $0$ may be.

Comment: My homework was about 15 questions, I solved most of them, these are the ones I couldn't do.

Answer (score 0):

$(a)$. $\bigg[\!\!\dfrac{-1\pm i\sqrt3}2\bigg]^3=1.\qquad\qquad$ $(b)$. Use [Stirling's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation). $\qquad\qquad(c)$. $\dfrac{x^n-1}{x-1}=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k$

Answer (score 0):

For the fourth question, expand  $ln(e^x+x)$ as a Taylor series at $x=0$. This gives $2 x-\frac{3 x^2}{2}$. Now, extract $x$ from each radical and remember that, if $y$ is small, $(1+y)^n$ can be approximated by $(1+n \space y)$. So, you should arrive to $-1$ but I let you doing something.